# How can I retrieve datatable rows, depending upon thead selected value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable. I am using  dynamic dropdowns in one column. Here I have taken one dropdown in `thead` of that particular column. Now if I select value from `thead`, then datatable.

Rows should retrieve from selected same value in dropdown.

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise the DataTable */
    var oTable = $('#dt3').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        }
    } );

    /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
    $("#status").each( function ( i ) {  // status is a id of thead dropdown
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {


        var sel= $(this).val(); 
        alert(sel);
  $(".statusselect option:selected").each(function() {
    var selectedvalue=$(this).text();
    if(sel==selectedvalue)
    alert($(this).text());
    oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
});

     //oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Here I am able to see only those who are opened with pagination same selected value from datatable. But how I can display *all* values from datatable using:

```
oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );  //$(this).val(), i
```

but I am not getting what I have to  mention here to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off pagination so all of the results are loaded.